# re-binding of .click() function gets fired in IE7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, click

Instead of just *binding* the function to the click event, my compare_remove() function actually gets *called* in IE7/8 (works fine in IE9, FF, Webkit).

HTML:

```
<div id="compare_listing_1234" class="compare_out_listing" title="Click to Add to Compare" onclick="compare_add('1234'); "></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function compare_add(pid) {
  $('#compare_listing_'+pid).removeClass("compare_out_listing").addClass("compare_in_listing");
  $('#compare_listing_'+pid).attr("title","Click to Remove from Compare");
  $('#compare_listing_'+pid).prop("onclick", null);
  $('#compare_listing_'+pid).unbind('click').click(function(){ compare_remove(pid); });
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I think I completely mis-read the question and butchered the title :( Please update/correct it if I did so.

Comment: I've reverted/updated the title :)

Comment: For anyone who has a similar problem... I ended up removing the onclick from the html, and used jQuery's click() event instead. So basically it's best not to use both onclick and click()/bind("click") together.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 8 will invoke event listeners added to the element during event dispatch. Firefox takes a snapshot of the event listeners as the event passes each element, so it won't invoke this particular event listener, but you could get it to invoke a bubbling event listener added by a capturing event listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare_add(pid) {
  window.event.cancelBubble = true;
  $('#compare_listing_'+pid).removeClass("compare_out_listing").addClass("compare_in_listing");
  $('#compare_listing_'+pid).attr("title","Click to Remove from Compare");
  $('#compare_listing_'+pid).prop("onclick", null);
  $('#compare_listing_'+pid).unbind('click').click(function(){ compare_remove(pid); });
}
```

Comment: Adding the *window.event.cancelBubble = true;* unfortunately didn't fix my problem (although I thought it might!)